# Could not resolve hostname for GitLab

Tags: shell, ssh, gitlab, host

So I just created a GitLab project and installed Git for windows, and after I generated/set up my ssh keys, the testing isn't successful:

```
C:\DiscordBot\SillyBot> ssh -vvvT git@Random-nii-chan
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.4
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\Random-nii-chan/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\ProgramData\\ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolving "random-nii-chan" port 22
C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\ssh.exe: Could not resolve hostname random-nii-chan: Unknown host.
```

I went to my git folder, created a .ssh directory and generated my keys in there (public and private).

What did i do wrong ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help. I created the conf file in a .ssh folder in %USERPROFILE% as you said, but when i run the test command, it says:

```
C:\DiscordBot\SillyBot>ssh -vvvT git@Random-nii-chan
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.4
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\Random-nii-chan/.ssh/config
debug1: C:\\Users\\Random-nii-chan/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for Random-nii-chan
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\ProgramData\\ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolving "git@random-nii-chan" port 22
ssh: Could not resolve hostname git@random-nii-chan: Une erreur irr\351cup\351rable s\222est produite lors d\222une recherche sur la base de donn\351es.
```

(an unfetchable error has occured while browsing the database, sorry if the translation is not correct)

Here is the content of my config file:

```
Host Random-nii-chan
    Hostname git@Random-nii-chan
    User git
    IdentityFile C:\DiscordBot\SillyBot\.ssh\gitlab
```

I edited it with the nano command

Comment: The hostname should be an actual hostname

Comment: Why using git@, when I say in my answer you don't have to?

Answer (score 0):

First, ssh does not look for your keys in "your git folder", but in %USERPROFILE%, in your case `C:\Users\Random-nii-chan`

Second, make sure you have a C:\Users\Random-nii-chan.ssh\config file (no extension, with LF end of lines, not CRLF) where you define what random-nii-chan is:

```
Host random-nii-chan
   Hostname yourGitLabserver.com
   User git
   IdentityFile c:/path/to/your/private/key
```

Then you can try `ssh -Tv random-nii-chan` (no need to add `git@`: the User is specified in the config file)